# Is there a particular reason why the progression I - II4/2 - V6/5 - I was such a popular opening progression for Baroque keyboard preludes?

Tags: harmony, improvisation

I'm currently reading John Mortensen's wonderful book on keyboard improvisation. (See [this link  here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0190920408).)

In the chapter on figuration preludes he states that the progression I - II4/2 - V6/5 - I was a popular "opener" or "page one" progression for such preludes. The most famous example being of course Bach's Prelude in C Major from WTC 1, BWV 846.

But why this particular progression? In particular, I wonder about the role of II4/2 here. Not by any stretch an uncommon chord in the late Baroque, but not particularly ubiquitous either.

Of course, the goal of any opening progression should be to establish the tonality firmly, but there must be dozens of progressions that accomplish this.

Comment: Was it as famous before the Bach Prelude, or did it really become popular afterwards?

Comment: @Richard: Honestly, I don't know. I suppose Bach wasn't the very first to come with it.

Comment: @Richard as far as I can tell there's no evidence that the Bach prelude was particularly widely known during the baroque period.

Comment: Now I really want to get that book!

Comment: @MichaelCurtis It does look good. I know you've cited Gjerdingen before, does he (or does Sanguinetti, etc.) ever mention this particular idiom?

Comment: @Richard, I don't think Gjerdingen mentions it. But, he does mention two "openers" QUISENZA, which uses a tonic pedal, and a version of ROMANESCA which uses a tonic `I2/4` they all share certain similar elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the part of the book on pages 6 and 7 (that's what I can see in the Amazon preview), the author gives `V6/5` in the harmonic skeleton, but some of the examples hold a tonic pedal for all the chords. So I think we need to be flexible about that particular chord.

When looking at the Bach example in `D` minor I notice, if you hold a tonic pedal and then play in the treble, the scale in thirds descending from the tonic, you pass through the sort of prototype "opener" harmony.

For simplicity, transposed to `C`...

[image]

I'm not sure this is really an answer. It's more an observation.

Of course `ii4/2` is then just the result of holding a pedal while the treble works through the motion that - despite the endless variety of figuration - can be viewed as a descent from the tonic by thirds.

Comment: See example 2.2, he really does specify it with the Roman numerals I mentioned. Otherwise I like your explanation, which seems to hint that it's basically just a harmonic elaboration of a pedal point. Mortensen does mention the Quiescenza schema as another popular opening.

Comment: @KimFierens, Yes, I missed it! I tried re-wording my answer accordingly.